# Trying to open .wmv file on ipad with VLC or Azul

Tags: ipad, video, vlc

I have some .wmv video files I want to play on my ipad. I had installed VLC player and it was playing them earlier. Recently, it seems to have stopped working. I even paid for and installed Azul player. Worked perfectly first time and since then, same behavior as VLC. This is what I do:

1. Go to "Files" app and find the .wmv file.
2. Tapping on it brings up a window and on the top right there is an "Open in Azul" option. There is also an icon with a square and arrow pointing out of it. I can press that and choose VLC too.
3. When I choose VLC or Azul to play the file this way, the VLC or Azul window pops up and it says "empty media library". The video doesn't play.

The annoying part is that it used to play some times in the past. Now, it just stopped playing altogether. What can I do to make these files play? They play just fine on my Android phone in VLC.

---

EDIT: I just realized that this behavior applies to all videos, not just .wmv files. If I try to open any video in VLC or Azul via the Files app ("open with"), it just opens VLC or Azul with the message "Empty Media library".

Also, I'm trying to play these files directly from a thumb drive connected via USB-C. If I copy them locally to the VLC folder, everything works.

Comment: Did it just stop playing the same video that played before or is it just not playing a new/different video?  Could these videos be DRM protected?

Comment: It's the same video. The behavior seemed to be non-deterministic before, sometimes paying sometimes not. Now, it just never plays.

Comment: What version of iPadOS?  Can you put a link to a sample video where you have this issue?

Comment: The iPadOS is 16.5. Actually, I now noticed that this holds for all videos, not just .wmv. If I try to open *any* video is VLC or Azul via the Files app, same thing happens. The apps just open with the message "Empty Media Library".

Comment: I can try to add a link, but again, this holds for any and all video.

Comment: I wanted to try and replicate

Comment: To replicate, put some large video files on a thumb drive. Then connect the thumb drive and try playing the videos directly from it. Its not the videos themselves because when I copy them over locally, they work.

Comment: I have large videos.  They play.  I wanted to see if it was related to the particular file you’re using.

Comment: I see. And they play directly from a thumb drive without copying them over locally as well?

Comment: I’ll have to test that.  I copy over all my videos for two reasons: a) the drive staying connected is (physically) inconvenient b) I like to have the port available for charging.      It’s important to remember that the Lightning port transfers  at USB2 speeds.